# What's the difference between stdout and STDOUT_FILENO?

Tags: c, linux, stdout

I'd like to know the difference between `stdout` and `STDOUT_FILENO` in Linux/C, and after some research I came to the following understanding:

- `stdout` belongs to the standard I/O stream of the C language, whose type is `FILE*` and is defined in `stdio.h`.
- `STDOUT_FILENO` is an `int` value defined in `unistd.h`. It's a file descriptor of LINUX system. In `unistd.h`, it's explained as follows:

> The following symbolic constants shall be defined for file streams:
>
> ```
> STDERR_FILENO
>     File number of stderr; 2.
> STDIN_FILENO
>     File number of stdin; 0.
> STDOUT_FILENO
>     File number of stdout; 1.
> ```

So, in my opinion, the `STDOUT_FILENO` belongs to system-level calling and, to some extent, is like a system API. `STDOUT_FILENO` can be used to describe any device in the system.

The `stdout` is located at a higher level (user level?) and actually encapsulate the details of `STDOUT_FILENO`; `stdout` has an I/O buffer.

That's my understanding about their differences. Could you help me review it and correct any mistake in it? Any comment or correction is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @KerrekSB The question is I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct?

Comment: `STDOUT_FILENO` is not *Linux* specific. All POSIX (and Unix) systems have it (e.g. also MacOSX or FreeBSD or Solaris)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`stdout` is a `FILE*` pointer giving the standard output stream. So obviously `fprintf(stdout, "x=%d\n", x);` has the same behavior as `printf("x=%d\n", x);`; you use `stdout` for `<stdio.h>` functions such as `fprintf()`, `fputs()` etc..

`STDOUT_FILENO` is an integer file descriptor (actually, the integer 1). You might use it for `write` syscall.

The relation between the two is `STDOUT_FILENO == fileno(stdout)`

<sup>(Except after you do weird things like `fclose(stdout);`, or perhaps some `freopen` after some `fclose(stdin)`, which you should almost never do! See [this](/q/25516375/4279), as commented by [J.F.Sebastian](/users/4279/j-f-sebastian))</sup>

You usually prefer the `FILE*` things, because they are buffered (so usually perform well). Sometimes, you may want to call `fflush()` to flush buffers.

You could use file descriptor numbers for [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) such as [`write()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) (which is used by the `stdio` library), or [`poll()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html). But using syscalls is clumsy. It may give you very good efficiency (but that is hard to code), but very often the `stdio` library is good enough (and more portable).

(Of course you should `#include <stdio.h>` for the stdio functions, and `#include <unistd.h>` - and some other headers - for the syscalls like `write`. And the stdio functions are implemented with syscalls, so `fprintf()` may call `write()`).

Comment: `STDOUT_FILENO == fileno(stdout)` Wonderful, this expression helps me totally understand this issue. Thanks a lot. @Basile

Comment: [`STDOUT_FILENO == fileno(stdout)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25516375/4279) -- is it always true?

Comment: File descriptors are also useful for redirecting streams to different places in the file descriptor table using `dup2` (for example, taking the output of a child process which makes some system call and prints to `stdout` and telling the OS to redirect that output to a text file before the system call is made)

Comment: I'm confused with `STDOUT_FILENO == fileno(stdout)` _unless_ you do something weird, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516375/is-it-possible-that-filenostdout-1-on-a-posix-system), to me it sounds like since  `STDOUT_FILENO != fileno(stdout)` is possible, wouldn't it be better to use `fileno(stdout)` in API? When do you actually need to use `STDOUT_FILENO` other than when comparing with `fileno(stdout)`?

Comment: @Rich, it's useful in programs that are not using `<stdio.h>`.  Just now, I found it useful when setting up redirection in a child process, for example, ensuring that its input and output streams were connected to the pipes I just created for it.