# Why does scanf returns control back to the program on pressing Enter key?

Tags: c, scanf

I wrote the following program.

```
void main()
{
   int   *piarrNumber1   = (int *) calloc(1, sizeof(int));
   int   iUserInput      = 0;

   scanf("%d", &iUserInput);
   piarrNumber1[(sizeof piarrNumber1 / sizeof(int)) - 1] = iUserInput;
   printf("\n%d\n", piarrNumber1[0]);
}
```

I input "3" followed by a TAB from the keyboard. Nothing happens. Then, I press Enter Key. I get "3" printed and the program ends.

If "TAB" [Horizanotal Tab] and "Enter" [Newline] are both whitespace characters, why is their behaviour different?

Comment: But that's because input is line buffered.

Comment: What is this "Line Buffering" about? Can we change this behaviour?

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted and voted to close. This is a great question, including a straight-forward example, and a clear description of the unexpected behavior.

Comment: On side note, `(sizeof piarrNumber1 / sizeof(int))` doesn't do what I think @PankajDwivedi thinks it does. I think that OP thinks it computes the array length, which would be true if `piarrNumber1` was an array. Since it is a pointer, it will always compute a small constant, probably 1, since the size of a pointer is usually the same as the size of an `int`.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why don't you use `ncurses` or `readline` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch those are not part of standard C

Comment: Neither is anything in my answer. I did assume Linux.

Comment: BTW, you should always test the return item count of `scanf` which can fail!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most OSes buffer keyboard input so that they can process backspaces properly -- the OS keeps input in a buffer and only gives it to the program  when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit.

Most OSes also provide ways to control this, but the way is different for different OSes.  On POSIX systems, the `tcsetattr` command is used to control this terminal buffering, along with lots of other things.  You can read the termios(3) manual page for lots of information about it.  You get the behavior you want by setting non-canonical mode:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    :
struct termios attr;
tcgetattr(0, &attr);
attr.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &attr);
```

which causes the OS to send every keystroke to your program immediately (except for a few special ones it intercepts, like <kbd>ctrl-C</kbd>), without waiting for <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and without processing backspaces either.

Note that terminal settings are persistent across programs that use the same terminal, so you probably want to save the original settings as of when your program started and restore them before it exits.

Comment: You might add the the terminal setting is somehow permanent (till changed by `termios` functions, or `stty` or `reset` commands). So a program doing that should ensure it is resetting the terminal to a sane state before exiting.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Will it be safe to assume that when accepting keyboard inputs for a C program run from a terminal in Unix and a Command line window in Windows, the default behaviour is to Line Buffer?

Comment: @PankajDwivedi:  On startup/login/window creation the terminal settings will initially be canonical (buffering up to enter and processing backspaces).  After that, they are whatever programs set them to.

Answer (score 5):

Details are operating system specific (since standard C99 does not know about terminals).

*I assume you are using **Linux**.*

First, [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is buffering the standard input stream and most other `FILE*` streams. You might try to change that with [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html), but this affects output buffering only.

More importantly, when *stdin* (actually the file descriptor used by it, i.e. `STDIN_FILENO` which is generally the value of `fileno(stdin)`) is a terminal (see [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to test that), the linux kernel is usually line-buffering the terminal (so called [cooked mode](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Cooked_Mode)) - at least to handle the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key. You might change that by switching the tty to raw mode (as every editor like `emacs` or `vim` or `nano` would do). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13104460/841108). But you should reset the cooked mode before your program exits.

So in normal cases, two levels of buffering happen: in the kernel for the line discipline of the terminal, and in the `libc` for the buffering of `stdin`

Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page and the [Text Terminal HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO.html)

In practice, **if you want sophisticated terminal input, use some library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) or [readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/)** (don't bother using just termios)

See also [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) & [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) & [tty_ioctl(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html); read about [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Notice that this line buferring at two levels (`libc` and kernel) is specific to ttys. When `stdin` is a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (as in `echo foo | yourprogram`) or a file (as in `yourprogram < yourinputfile.txt`) things are different.

In short, ttys are hard to understand, because they mimic complex and arcane hardware devices of the 1950s-1970s era.

Comment: Thanks, sir! I can understand the Buffering theory now. Is LINE BUFFERING the default for stdio stream?

Comment: Not every *stdio* stream is line buffered, but I believe those for ttys are. Details give me headache (even if I understood almost all of them before). So if you want to have better terminal input, use `ncurses` or `readline`

Comment: Actually stdio buffering is completely irrelevant for input, as it is always buffered (needs a place to put characters read), and `scanf` reads from that buffer.  The issue here is terminal buffering, controlled by `tcsetattr`.

Comment: I am not sure it is. To use `stdin` with less buffering, you'll need both to set the tty to raw mode and to set `setvbuf` the `stdin`; but that would be silly (better use `ncurses`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `setvbuf` only controls output buffering -- it has no effect on stdin or input of any kind.