# execute after EOF in C

Tags: c, input, eof

I'm doing homework for my C programming class.  The question states "Write a program which reads input as a stream of characters until encountering EOF".  I'm using Xcode on my macbook and the only way I know to make the program encounter EOF is using ctrl + D or ctrl + Z.  But it will exit my program completely.

For example I have this code:

```
int main()
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putchar(ch);

    }
    printf("%d",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there away for the code to execute the printf("%d",ch) after the loop (after i hit ctrl + D on my keyboard)?

Comment: You'll have to press Enter at least once before hitting Ctrl-D.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths is it really so?

Comment: @dattran it should print -1 or something. are you sure you're not missing the o/p because of lack of a `\n` in the print statement?

Comment: i tried and it doesn't work. everytime i use ctrl + D to input the EOF there's a -1 and it exits my program

Comment: `EOF` **is** `-1`. So what would expect `printf("%d",ch);` to print out?

Comment: The ascii number of the inputs

Comment: It's outputting the code of the **last** input character, which happens to be EOF, hence -1.

Comment: To print the ascii number of the inputs change `putchar(ch);` to `printf("%d," ch);`

Comment: yes i'm running from a command line.

Comment: @DatTran Your program does what your homework says to do.  It reads input from the stdin stream until an EOF is encountered.  When you don't redirect the input from a file or something, then it is up to you to type in the input at the terminal and to indicate when you are done with a ctrl-D. :)

Comment: Your program is executing the `printf("%d", ch);` If your IDE is popping up a window to run your program and then quickly closing it when the program exits, then you could change your printf to be `printf("\n%d\n", ch);` (which will always print -1, btw) and then put a call to `pause();` (you'll need to #include <unistd.h>) at the end of your program just before you return from main. That will cause it to pause until you send it a signal (e.g. - ctrl-C). If you are running from the command line of a shell, then you shouldn't need this.

Answer (score 2):

You can test your program using (with a POSIX shell) [here documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

First compile your source code `mycode.c` into a binary `mybin` with

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g mycode.c -o mybin
```

(it could be `clang` or `cc` instead of `gcc`)

then run `mybin` with a "here document" like

```
 ./mybin << EOF
    here is my 
    input
 EOF
```

You could also use input redirection. Make some file `myfile.txt` and run `./mybin < myfile.txt`

You could even run your program on its own source code: `./mybin < mycode.c`

And the input could even come from some pipe, e.g. `ls * | ./mybin`

BTW, what you are observing is that `stdin`, when it is a terminal, is line-buffered. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29058076/841108) (most of it should apply to MacOSX).

Notice that your code is incorrect: you are missing an `#include <stdio.h>` near the top of the file, and your `main` should really be `int main(int argc, char**argv)` (BTW you could improve your program so that when arguments are given, they are file names to be read). At last the ending `printf` would surely show -1 which is generally the value of `EOF`

Also, it is much better to end your `printf` format control string with `\n` or else use appropriately [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

Notice that end-of-file is *not* an input (or a valid `char`), it is a condition on some input file stream like `stdin`, and the [getchar(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html) function is specified to return `EOF` which is an `int` outside of the range of `char` (on my Linux system `EOF` is -1 because `char`-s are between 0 and 255 included). You might test end-of-file condition *after* some input operation (*never* before!) using [feof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html)

A terminal in usual cooked mode is handled by the kernel so that when you press <kbd>*Ctrl*   D</kbd> an end-of-file *condition* is triggered on the file descriptor (often `STDIN_FILENO` i.e. 0) related to that terminal.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using Xcode on my macbook and the only way I know to make the program encounter EOF is using ctrl + D or ctrl + Z. But it will exit my program completely.

No it won't.  If you run your program in the Xcode debugger, provided the console pane has the focus, all input you type will go to your program (note that, by default, stdin is line buffered, so you'll only see output when you press the return key).  If you hit control-d (not control-z), you're program will exit the loop and print -1 in the console window (which is what you expect because that is the value of EOF in OS X).

Here is the result when I ran your program without change in the Xcode debugger (I typed command-r in Xcode)

`bgbgdfsfd`
**`bgbgdfsfd`**
`hgfdgf`
**`hgfdgf`**
**`-1`**

Regular font was typed by me, bold font was from your program.  At the end of each of the lines typed by me, I pressed carriage return.  After your program printed `hgfdgf` I typed  control-D.  Your program then printed the value of the last thing it got from `getchar()` which was `EOF` which is `-1` in the OS X C library.

---

**Edit**

If you are unsure that your program is printing the EOF, change your `printf` format string to (for example)

```
printf("Last character is [%d]\n", ch);
```

Then instead of `-1` your program will output `Last character is [-1]` on the last line.

Comment: so if it got EOF it should exit the loop and execute the printf?  Did you get the printf results?

Comment: @DatTran  Yes, that is what the `-1` is at the end of the output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ctrl+z` does not input EOF to your program. If you hit `ctrl+Z` your shell will put your program to sleep.

Second, if you want to handle these `ctrl+Z` in your program you need to learn about signal handling in C.

And I think because you were hitting `ctrl+Z` you were not seeing any output on the screen.

Comment: OP, `CTRL+Z` is `EOF` in Windows

Comment: @AlterMann: the OP is using a Mac.

Comment: `CTRL-D` is `EOF` on Unix and Mac OSX. There is no signal involved in handling of `CTRL-D`.

Comment: So is there a different method to input EOF? without exitting my program?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I know, it was a comment for OP ;)

Comment: Stop using phrases like 'CTRL-D is EOF'.  Typing Ctrl-D simply closes the input stream.  When the input stream is closed, getchar returns a value which happens to be designated 'EOF', but it is not correct to say that "an eof is sent".  The stream is closed.  EOS.  (end of story).

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes this is more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are sending the EOF signal, not a signal that actually terminates your program.

For example, for c program running in windows the EOF is represent by typing ctrl+z and pressing enter. Doing this will exit your while loop but still runs the rest of your program.

However, ctrl+c, which some people may have mistakenly tried for EOF, actually kills your program and will prevent the code behind your while loop from executing.

For mac you will need to find what is the input that corresponds to EOF, and make sure that is what you are sending through rather than the kill signal, which I suspect is what you are doing here.