# Something strange happens during debugging in CLion while running is OK

Tags: c, file-io, io, ide, clion

I am college student, learning C. I use CLion 2018.2.5 in macOS 10.14 mojave.

It's an easy problem "A plus B", here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b;
    while (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != EOF) {
        printf("%d", a + b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: There is NO Newline '\n' after "%d".

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓Output by clicking Debug in CLion:

(I typed "4 space 5 return 6 space 7 return command+D(EOF)")

```
/Users/i/CLionProjects/C_PersonalPractice/cmake-build-debug/sum
4 5
6 7 
^D
913
Process finished with exit code 0
```

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓Output by clicking Run in CLion:

(I typed "4 space 5 return 6 space 7 return command+D(EOF)")

```
/Users/i/CLionProjects/C_PersonalPractice/cmake-build-debug/sum
4 5
96 7
13^D

Process finished with exit code 0
```

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓Output by GCC in Terminal:

(I typed: "4 space 5 return 6 space 7 return control+D(EOF)")

```
Last login: Fri Oct 26 13:35:34 on ttys005
MacBook-Pro:~ i$ /Users/i/sum ; exit;
4 5
96 7
13logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[进程已完成]
```

In the debugging result, I found the IDE seems to display the calculation result together instead of displaying it instantly after entering two numbers.

Is it a feature or bug about debugging of CLion?

### Update:

This code can be OK successfully during debugging as long as I type newline '\n' after "%d".

In addition, today I just encountered another similar bug related to EOF:

[sending EOF to stdin in Clion IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405577/sending-eof-to-stdin-in-clion-ide);

[execute after EOF in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075514/execute-after-eof-in-c);

which had been confirmed by JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5704

Its solution is to disable "run.processes.with.pty" in Registry in CLion.

---

I think this problem could be complicated if considering all of the above factors: Debug or Run, type newline or not, disable or enable "run.processes.with.pty".

Comment: OT: `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != EOF` ==> `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) == 2`

Comment: @4386427 I did this to clearly reflect the number entered and the calculation result. (I thought) It doesn't matter, certainly I re-edited it. I thought the problem is the IDE seems to display the calculation result together instead of displaying it instantly after entering two numbers.

Comment: The clion debugger output is not correctly line buffered (the program sees it as a non-interactive device)