# What standard input and output would be if there's no terminal connected to server?

Tags: stdout, stdin

This question came up into my mind when I was thinking about ways of server logging yesterday.

Normally, we open a terminal connected to local computer or remote server, run an executable, and print (`printf`, `cout`) some debug/log information in the terminal.

But for those processes/executables/scripts running on the server which are not connected to a terminal, what are the standard input and output?

For example:

1. Suppose I have a `crontab` task, running a program on the server many times a day. If I write something like `cout << "blablabla" << endl;` in the program. What's gonna happen? Where those output will flow into?
2. Another example I came up and wanted to know is, if I write a CGI program (use `C` or `C++`) for let's say a Apache web server,  what is the standard input and output of my CGI program ? (According to this `C++` CGI [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm), I guess the standard input and output of the CGI program are in some ways redirected to the Apache server. Because it's using `cout` to output the html contents, not by `return`. )

I've read this [What is “standard input”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540425/what-is-standard-input) before asking, which told me standard input isn't necessary to be tied to keyboard while standard output isn't necessary to be tied to a terminal/console/screen.

OS is Linux.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Whatever it will be, then what exactly `STDIN` and `STDOUT` will be? I just remembered that those programs which are not connected to a terminal need to do some operations to close standard input and output and then "detach" from the terminal and eventually they become "daemon" processes. Standard input and output are eventually closed for those programs.

Comment: I assume STDIN and STDOUT are connected to /dev/null on Linux. But this depends on the OS. What OS are you using? When a process is started a file descriptor is connected to STDIN resp. STDOUT. You can change it with `>` resp. `2>`.

Comment: This question is not related to C or C++ or to programming in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard input and standard output (and standard error) streams can point to basically any I/O device.  This is commonly a terminal, but it can also be a file, a pipe, a network socket, a printer, etc.  What exactly those streams direct their I/O to is usually determined by the process that launches your process, be that a shell or a daemon like cron or apache, but a process can redirect those streams itself it it would like.

I'll use Linux as an example, but the concepts are similar on most other OSes.  On Linux, the standard input and standard output stream are represented by file descriptors `0` and `1`.  The macros `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` are just for convenience and clarity.  A file descriptor is just a number that matches up to some file description that the OS kernel maintains that tells it how to write to that device.  That means that from a user-space process's perspective, you write to pretty much anything the same way: `write(some_file_descriptor, some_string, some_string_length)` (higher-level I/O functions like `printf` or `cout` are just wrappers around one or more calls to `write`).  To the process, it doesn't matter what type of device `some_file_descriptor` represents.  The OS kernel will figure that out for you and pass your data to the appropriate device driver.

---

The standard way to launch a new process is to call `fork` to duplicate the parent process, and then later to call one of the `exec` family of functions in the child process to start executing some new program.  In between, it will often close the standard streams it inherited from its parent and open new ones to redirect the child process's output somewhere new.  For instance, to have the child pipe its output back to the parent, you could do something like this in C++:

```cpp
int main()
{
    // create a pipe for the child process to use for its
    // standard output stream
    int pipefds[2];
    pipe(pipefds);

    // spawn a child process that's a copy of this process
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // we're now in the child process

        // we won't be reading from this pipe, so close its read end
        close(pipefds[0]);
        // we won't be reading anything
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        // close the stdout stream we inherited from our parent
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        // make stdout's file descriptor refer to the write end of our pipe
        dup2(pipefds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        // we don't need the old file descriptor anymore.
        // stdout points to this pipe now
        close(pipefds[1]);
        // replace this process's code with another program
        execlp("ls", "ls", nullptr);
    } else {
        // we're still in the parent process

        // we won't be writing to this pipe, so close its write end
        close(pipefds[1]);

        // now we can read from the pipe that the
        // child is using for its standard output stream
        std::string read_from_child;
        ssize_t count;
        constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE = 100;
        char buf[BUF_SIZE];
        while((count = read(pipefds[0], buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
            std::cout << "Read " << count << " bytes from child process\n";
            read_from_child.append(buf, count);
        }

        std::cout << "Read output from child:\n" << read_from_child << '\n';
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Note: I've omitted error handling for clarity

This example creates a child process and redirects its output to a pipe.  The program run in the child process (`ls`) can treat the standard output stream just as it would if it were referencing a terminal (though `ls` changes some behaviors if it detects its standard output isn't a terminal).

---

This sort of redirection can also be done from a terminal.  When you run a command you can use the redirection operators to tell your shell to redirect that commands standard streams to some other location than the terminal.  For instance, here's a convoluted way to copy a file from one machine to another using an sh-like shell:

```
gzip < some_file | ssh some_server 'zcat > some_file'
```

This does the following:

1. create a pipe
2. run `gzip` redirecting its standard input stream to read from "some_file" and redirecting its standard output stream to write to the pipe
3. run `ssh` and redirect its standard input stream to read from the pipe
4. on the server, run `zcat` with its standard input redirected from the data read from the ssh connection and its standard output redirected to write to "some_file"