# Difference of fs.readFileSync() on '/dev/stdin' or `process.stdin.fd`?

Tags: node.js

```
$ cat main.js 
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

fs=require('fs');
//data=fs.readFileSync(process.stdin.fd);
data=fs.readFileSync('/dev/stdin');
console.log(data.toString());
$ ./main.js <<< 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
```

It seems that both `'/dev/stdin'` and `process.stdin.fd` works the same at least in my environment (Mac OS X). Are they always work the same on Unix variant systems? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin), `process.stdin.fd` can point either to a `net.Socket` **or** a file when fd0 refers to it.
In the first case it's a Duplex stream, in the second it's a Readable stream. On the other hand, fd0 still technically is *stdin* as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367920/is-it-possible-that-linux-file-descriptor-0-1-2-not-for-stdin-stdout-and-stderr) in both cases.
Node had some issues regarding this functionality on OS X, you can read about them [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7439).

I think you can assume that `/dev/stdin` and `process.stdin.fd` are interchangeable on Unix variant systems, but I would prefer to use `/dev/stdin` because `process.stdin.fd` has been used mainly for debugging purposes in Node.