# use stdout as the first argument of write

Tags: c, stdout, system-calls

I use the `write` syscall using the `unistd.h` header to send text to stdout. AFAIK, the numeric value of *stdout* is **1**. So why can't I use `stdout` instead of `1` as the first argument of `write`?

```
#include <unistd.h> // write
#include <stdio.h> // stdout

int main(void)
{
    write(stdout, "This will be output to standard out\n", 36);
    return 0;
}
```

Google said: *Standard output value stdout. Its value is 1.*

Comment: `1` is an `int`; `stdout` is a `FILE*`

Comment: @pmg Why? I can't get it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902627/the-difference-between-stdout-and-stdout-fileno-in-linux-c

Comment: Because [C11 7.21...](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21): the header `<stdio.h>` defines ... `stdout` which is expression of type ''pointer to FILE''

Comment: You can't use `stdout` but you can use `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to write is a *file descriptor*, which is an integer.  This is the native Unix I/O.

`stdout` here is an object that is intended for use with C library I/O routines.  It is a pointer to an internal `FILE` object. It is not an integer.

`stdout` in other contexts means other things. We often use it to refer to the Unix concept of the 'standard output' file descriptor, which is indeed 1. But that doesn't mean that 'stdout' in an arbitrary programming language is identically equal to 1.  Rather, it will be whatever mechanism the language runtime needs to handle the output.